# Batch API error: ResponseText: {"errors":[{"message":"Not acceptable format: json"}]}

Tags: 8, batch-operations

When running a batch process on Drupal 8, the following error is returned:

```
ResponseText: {"errors":[{"message":"Not acceptable format: json"}]}
```

The HTTP response is HTTP POST / 406

I can see the route is defined ok for the batch callback with the JSON support there:

```
select * from router where name like '%system.batch_page%' \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           name: system.batch_page.html
           path: /batch
pattern_outline: /batch
            fit: 1
          route: C:31:"Symfony\Component\Routing\Route":970:{a:9:{s:4:"path";s:6:"/batch";s:4:"host";s:0:"";s:8:"defaults";a:2:{s:11:"_controller";s:52:"\Drupal\system\Controller\BatchController::batchPage";s:15:"_title_callback";s:57:"\Drupal\system\Controller\BatchController::batchPageTitle";}s:12:"requirements";a:2:{s:7:"_access";s:4:"TRUE";s:7:"_format";s:4:"html";}s:7:"options";a:4:{s:14:"compiler_class";s:34:"\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteCompiler";s:12:"_admin_route";b:1;s:12:"_no_big_pipe";b:1;s:14:"_access_checks";a:1:{i:0;s:20:"access_check.default";}}s:7:"schemes";a:0:{}s:7:"methods";a:2:{i:0;s:3:"GET";i:1;s:4:"POST";}s:9:"condition";s:0:"";s:8:"compiled";C:33:"Drupal\Core\Routing\CompiledRoute":312:{a:11:{s:4:"vars";a:0:{}s:11:"path_prefix";s:0:"";s:10:"path_regex";s:12:"#^/batch$#sD";s:11:"path_tokens";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"text";i:1;s:6:"/batch";}}s:9:"path_vars";a:0:{}s:10:"host_regex";N;s:11:"host_tokens";a:0:{}s:9:"host_vars";a:0:{}s:3:"fit";i:1;s:14:"patternOutline";s:6:"/batch";s:8:"numParts";i:1;}}}}
   number_parts: 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           name: system.batch_page.json
           path: /batch
pattern_outline: /batch
            fit: 1
          route: C:31:"Symfony\Component\Routing\Route":858:{a:9:{s:4:"path";s:6:"/batch";s:4:"host";s:0:"";s:8:"defaults";a:1:{s:11:"_controller";s:52:"\Drupal\system\Controller\BatchController::batchPage";}s:12:"requirements";a:2:{s:7:"_access";s:4:"TRUE";s:7:"_format";s:4:"json";}s:7:"options";a:3:{s:14:"compiler_class";s:34:"\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteCompiler";s:12:"_admin_route";b:1;s:14:"_access_checks";a:1:{i:0;s:20:"access_check.default";}}s:7:"schemes";a:0:{}s:7:"methods";a:2:{i:0;s:3:"GET";i:1;s:4:"POST";}s:9:"condition";s:0:"";s:8:"compiled";C:33:"Drupal\Core\Routing\CompiledRoute":312:{a:11:{s:4:"vars";a:0:{}s:11:"path_prefix";s:0:"";s:10:"path_regex";s:12:"#^/batch$#sD";s:11:"path_tokens";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"text";i:1;s:6:"/batch";}}s:9:"path_vars";a:0:{}s:10:"host_regex";N;s:11:"host_tokens";a:0:{}s:9:"host_vars";a:0:{}s:3:"fit";i:1;s:14:"patternOutline";s:6:"/batch";s:8:"numParts";i:1;}}}}
   number_parts: 1
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just wondering if anyone else has encountered this error for the Batch API processing and may have some suggestions on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our case, we had to turn off Cloudflare's `Query String Sort` option. See here --> https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022037774-Resolving-Not-acceptable-format-json-error-HTTP-code-406-in-batch-operations

Here is the drupal issue too --> https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2879023